# SQLAlchemy getting a row using filter() but not with get() function

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy==1.3.18 and Flask==1.1.2

My problem is that I want to update a row that's inserted using a Stored Procedure. Here is my process:

My engine to the DB:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://db_user:db_password@db_host:db_port')
```

My model

```
class Employee(declararive_base()):
    __tablename__ = "EMPLOYEE"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(30))
    last_name = Column(String(30))
```

I execute a Stored Procedure using this function:

```
def call_procedure(function_name, params):
       connection = cloudsql.Engine.raw_connection()
       try:
           cursor = connection.cursor()
           cursor.callproc(function_name, params)
           results = list(cursor.fetchall())
           cursor.close()
           connection.commit()
           return results
       finally:
           connection.close()
```

Then, I recover the id of the inserted record and set the value on this variable `new_employee_id`.

After that I try to execute this: `session.query(Employee).get(new_employee_id)` and I get `None`.
But if I do the query using `session.query(Employee).filter(Employee.id == new_employee_id).all()`
I get the record.

Any ideas about this?

I'm thinking that maybe the get method works over the index and since the table is not reindexed again at that moment, the query cannot get the record. What happens with the filter is that it searches on the whole table and can get the record.

Update: My model class was added to this question.

Update2: I added how I create my engine on SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Is `id` the primary key on the table?  Ideally this question should include the code for the model class.

Comment: What dialect and driver are you using? For example, `mysql+pymysql://`

Comment: Hi Leticia, 
Please include the Model class as well as the value of `new_employee_id`

Comment: @Leticia - I am unable to reproduce your issue. [This code](https://pastebin.com/9TMrKrVT) works fine for me.